# How to create an AUC custom function in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I am trying to create two custom functions `f1_metric` and `auc_metric` in Keras. The `f1_metric` works, but the auc not, and I receive different errors. Here is my code:

```
def f1_metric(y_true, y_pred):
    true_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true * y_pred, 0, 1)))
    possible_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_true, 0, 1)))
    predicted_positives = K.sum(K.round(K.clip(y_pred, 0, 1)))
    precision = true_positives / (predicted_positives + K.epsilon())
    recall = true_positives / (possible_positives + K.epsilon())
    f1_val = 2*(precision*recall)/(precision+recall+K.epsilon())
    
    return f1_val  

def auc_metric(y_true, yhat):
    
    yhat = yhat[:, 1]

    # calculate roc curves
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, yhat)
    auc=auc(tpr,fpr)
    return auc
```

Here are my compile and fit codes:

```
   opt = SGD(lr=0.01,momentum=0.9) 
   model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy']) # 
   ca = SnapshotEnsemble(n_epochs, n_cycles, 0.01)

  # fit model
  history=model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=n_epochs, 
   verbose='auto', callbacks=[ca],batch_size=32)
```

Any Idea how to solve it? I want to define a similar function as I did for f1_metric.

Comment: In case you missed this, `keras` has AUC implemented -> https://keras.io/api/metrics/classification_metrics/#auc-class

Comment: Yes, it works. Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Approximates the AUC (Area under the curve) of the ROC or PR curves.
>
> ```
> tf.keras.metrics.AUC(
>     num_thresholds=200, curve='ROC',
>     summation_method='interpolation', name=None, dtype=None,
>     thresholds=None, multi_label=False, num_labels=None, label_weights=None,
>     from_logits=False
> )
> ```

For more details you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC)

(paraphrased from Captain Trojan)